# highlight text / tokens in input field - slack search box styles

Tags: html, css, dom

I love the way slack did their highlight of keywords and values in their search I wanted to do something similar.

For those who don't know how it looks a screenshot :

[image: slack search]

when you inspect slack dom and css, it's something like this

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <input id="search-query">

    <div class="highlighter_underlay">
        regurlar text that doesn't match keyword:value goes here  
        <span class="modifier">key:</span>
        <span class="keyword">value</span>
        or here  
        <span class="ghost_text">hint</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So i'm positioning div over input using absolute positioning, setting .highlighter_underlay text to equal contents of value, tokenize input, adding nice styling to .modifier and .keyword - all easy and works and looks great.

But there is one thing i don't know how to deal with.

Notice that input has a fixed width, but you can enter more text into input and it will overflow and be hidden.

[image: overflow]

Question is how do you move your overlay div in sync with text input text as it has to align? Please notice that div overlay had to be moved.

[image: overlay is moved]

It seems it's some css positioning trick, as i don't see any css properties changing when i type more text into input so i don't think it's javascript, neither i could find anything specific in their css that would do that ...

Any ideas?

Here's a link to a prototype:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYZzeB

Comment: reproducing it on fiddle helps us to fit it easily

Comment: added a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYZzeB

Comment: Maybe it's all contained in a parent element with a fixed width but hidden overflow, and the input is much wider, so when the caret goes outside of the visible area, the parent element shifts its viewable area - then the highlight overlay still has the same position relative to the input, it's just the viewable area of the parent element that changes.

Comment: entire input is visible, besides how would you know `when the caret goes outside of the visible area` ?

Answer (score 0):

One method to move an element relative to its parent is to use the CSS combination of:

Parent element using: `position: relative`

Child element using: `position: absolute`

**[CODEPEN Example](http://codepen.io/pohuski/pen/Gpdmbp)**: This simple example illustrates the relative relationship.

In the live Slack code you referenced, the actual styling box is coming from the [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) `::before`. When this is set absolute to its relative-set parent, it will follow the relativity of that parent -- thus enabling it to track left and right relative to the parent.